# Why can't I access value in a vector using "print" in gdb debugger?

Tags: c++, vector, gdb

I'm learning to use the gdb debugger but having trouble accessing the values of a vector when that vector contains values copied from another vector. Ultimately the program below does what I want it to do (copies the values of "nums" into a new vector "copyOfNums"), but when I try to examine the value at copyOfNums[0] after executing the first for loop in "copyNums", the value in memory can't be accessed (see gdb session below).

Below copy nums has executed 1 loop of the for statement, so should copyNums[0] contain the address of the value pointed to by nums[0] or should it contain a reference to a new int (that is the same as the l-value pointed to by nums[0])? Regardless I would expect to be able to access the value, but as you can see from the following gdb output, it is inaccessible.

```
Breakpoint 1, copyNums (nums=@0x7fff5fbffad0) at main.cpp:10

(gdb) print nums[0]
$1 = (int &) @0x100103910: 2
(gdb) print copyOfNums[0]
$2 = (int &) @0x0: Cannot access memory at address 0x0
(gdb) 

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<int> copyNums(vector<int> nums){
  int sizeNums = nums.size();
  vector<int> copyOfNums;

=>for (int i = 0; i < sizeNums; i++){
    copyOfNums.push_back(nums[i]);
  }

  return copyOfNums;
}

vector<int> getSmallNums(){

  vector<int> nums;
  nums.push_back(2);
  nums.push_back(1);
  nums.push_back(8);

  return nums;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    vector<int> nums = getSmallNums();
    vector<int> copyOfNums = copyNums(nums);


    return 0;
}
```

Here is the gbd output after sort has returned. Looks like the copy contains a reference to a new location in memory, the l-value of which is 2 (as expected). Why was I unable to access copyOfNums[0] within the function copyNums?

```
(gdb) print nums[0]
$3 = (int &) @0x1001000e0: 2
(gdb) print copyOfNums[0]
$4 = (int &) @0x100103920: 2
```

EDIT: here is a more complete picture of the debugging session

```
(gdb) info locals
i = 1
sizeNums = 3
copyOfNums = {
  <std::_Vector_base<int,std::allocator<int> >> = {
    _M_impl = {
      <std::allocator<int>> = {
        <__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>},
      members of std::_Vector_base<int,std::allocator<int> >::_Vector_impl:
      _M_start = 0x0,
      _M_finish = 0x0,
      _M_end_of_storage = 0x0
    }
  }, <No data fields>}
(gdb) print copyOfNums[0]
$1 = (const int &) @0x0: Cannot access memory at address 0x0
```

Comment: I suggest you change the declaration of `copyNums` to this: `vector<int> copyNums(vector<int> const &nums)`  Your code is copying the entire vector of integers onto the stack, to pass by value, when all you need to pass is a const reference.

Comment: Counting the line numbers beginning with `#include <iostream>`, then the breakpoint at line 10 stops execution at `int sizeNums = nums.size();`. `copyOfNums` has no elements at this point, have you stepped into the loop with gdb next or step?

Comment: oops I deleted part of by debugging session in which i hit "next" a number of times after the initial break--so at this point it had gone through one iteration of the loop.

Comment: also, thanks for the suggestion regarding changing it to const &nums!

Comment: Can you try to compile it with the `-gstab+` compiler option and try to debug it again (I had similar problems with DWARF 2)?

Comment: is that instead of -g?

Comment: I tried it in addition to -g and added the most recent debugging session to my original post

Comment: It's instead of `-g` (`-g` selects the format itself), in another try you maybe could print the value of `copyOfNums[i]` to `cout` after the `push_back` instruction.

Comment: I tried running it like: g++ -Wall -c -gstab+ main.cpp, but got the following error:
cc1plus: error: unrecognised debug output level "stab+"
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
make: Target `p1' not remade because of errors.

Comment: Sorry, it's `-gstabs+`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how much a compiler will be able to optimize this away, but in reality, this code:

```
vector<int> copyNums(vector<int> nums){
  int sizeNums = nums.size();
  vector<int> copyOfNums;

  for (int i = 0; i < sizeNums; i++){
    copyOfNums.push_back(nums[i]);
  }

  return copyOfNums;
}
```

Has the same result as this code:

```
vector<int> copyNums(vector<int> nums){
  return nums;
}
```

If a compiler is doing an optimization like that, or a number of other possible optimizations, `copyofNums` could be completely optimized away.

Comment: user2016050 should try compiling with all optimizations disabled and debugging enabled.  If the problem doesn't reproduce, then this was it.

Comment: Hmm, I tried this on Linux with `g++ -O3 -g` and gdb showed that there really was a `copyOfNums` for me.

Comment: I was using a makefile to compile this (which is also something I'm new to), so I modified it to look like: OBJS = main.o
CC = g++
DEBUG = -g -O0
CFLAGS = -Wall -c $(DEBUG)
LFLAGS = -Wall $(DEBUG) 

p1 : $(OBJS)
 $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o p1

main.o : main.cpp 
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.cpp

clean:
 \rm *.o *~ p1

tar:
 tar cfv p1.tar main.cpp

Comment: sorry, I pasted that in sloppily--it's correctly formatted in the real file, basically I just added -O0 after -g in DEBUG. Was this what you were recommending?

Comment: Well, in my testing, I think gcc might be optimizing it away at -O0. clang, for example, does not and behaves as you expect under a debugger.

Comment: Interesting...I'm not familiar with clang, is there a change I can make to my makefile to get it to work using gdb?

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer part of your question.

> copyNums[0] contain the address of the value pointed to by nums[0] or
>   should it contain a reference to a new int (that is the same as the
>   l-value pointed to by nums[0])?

Terminology you used ( new, reference ) seems confusing to me.

`copyNums[0]` contains a **copy** of the value at `num[0]`. `&nums[0]` is different from `&copyNums[0]`. And `nums[0]` contains a value of `int` type. So, `copyNums[0]` neither contains the address of the location nums[0] nor it contains a reference to a new int.

Comment: Sorry about that--that was confusing terminology I used. When I run whatis numCopy[0] I see that it is a int&, and that means it contains an address, right? An address that points to an int? I keep thinking I understand pointers and then I realize I'm not yet 100% there...